# How to keep included LESS files from compiling on their own, as with SCSS?

Tags: css, less

I'm more familiar with SASS, wherein I can create scss files that start with an underscore so that the scss compiler ignores them.  I then import these files into a main.scss file, and they are then compiled into that. Then my HTML onlt links to the main file.

Is there a similar mechanism for LESS?  I know how to import files into a LESS file, but will the child LESS files compile to separate CSS files anyway?

Comment: LESS does work in a similar way as SASS. If you only convert the main LESS file to CSS than it will resolve all imports and create a single CSS file. Depending on the tool you use for conversion this might need some configuration.

Comment: It depends on the tool you are using to compile your less to css. Some  tools have a specific option to do what you want. What are you using?

Comment: I am using Codekit, watching the project folder and it works the same way as sass.  not sure if other methods work.

Comment: In Codekit, you can select all the "children" and right click "Set to not compile directly"

Comment: yes, apparently starting the name with an underscore accomplishes that automatically.

Comment: I didn't know, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I did some experiments, and apparently the underscore at the name beginning works for LESS as it does SASS. (At least using CodeKit on Mac).